# why cloud platforms are getting more popular now a days as though they are costly?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, push-notification, cloud, cloud-platform

Currently i am trying to learn various **Services of Amazon web services** and **Microsoft windows azure** like **Amazon sns**,**Amazon Storage**,**amazon Search**.

I am having some question in my mind that why now a days cloud platforms are getting so popular than old traditional approach like previously we were storing our files(img,txt,.doc etc) in our web application project only but now adays some web application are storing their files on amazon storage or on azure storage.

What is the benefits of storing files and folders over cloud platform ??

> Next why amazon search or azure search is preferred as when they were
>   not available searching was done and amazon and azure search are not
>   freely availabale??
>
> Now if we talk about push notification then why to use amazon or azure
>   push notification if we can easily send notification through codes
>   that are available on internet??

I general i just want to know that why now a days web application are using more cloud platforms(Azure or amazon) even though they are costly??

Can anybody explain me this with some details??

Comment: perhaps your premise (*even though they are costly*) is misleading.

Answer (score 3):

Among the many reasons, the most important and common ones I can think of are:

**High Availability** - When you manage your own services, there is always an operational challenge of ensuring that they do not go down i.e, crash. This may cause a downtime to your application or even data loss depending on the situation. The cloud services you have mentioned, offer reliable solutions that guarantee maximum up time and data safety (by backup, for example). They often replicate your data across multiple servers, so that even if one of their servers are down, you do not loose any data.

**Ease of use** - Cloud services make it very easy to use a specific service by providing detailed documentation and client libraries to use their services. The dashboard or console of many cloud services are often user friendly and do not require extensive technical background to use. You could deploy a Hadoop cluster in Google Compute Engine in less than a minute, for instance. They offer many pre-built solutions which you can take advantage of.

**Auto-Scale** - Many cloud services nowadays are designed to scale automatically. The are built to scale automatically with increasing traffic. You do not have to worry about the traffic or application load.

**Security** - Cloud services are secure. They offer sophisticated security solutions using which, you can secure your service from being misused.

**Cost** -  Trying to host your own services require extensive resources like high end servers, dedicated system administrators, good network connectivity etc. Cloud services are quite cheap these days.

Of course you could solve these problems yourself, **but** smaller organizations often do not prefer to do so because of the operational overhead. It would take  more time and resources to reach a stage where your solution is both reliable and functional. People would often prefer to work on the actual problem their application is trying to solve and abstract away most operational problems which cloud services readily offer.

p.s. These are some opinions from an early stage startup perspective.

Comment: My 2 to 3 questions are still not answered yet

Comment: Could you please rephrase / clarify:

"Next why amazon search or azure search is preferred as when they were not available searching was done and amazon and azure search are not freely availabale??"

Comment: Reg push notifications - It is yet another cloud service which would be used for the same reasons as mentioned above. For example, You could write a push notification server and host it your self. But, you might have to write code for each new client platform you wish to support. In Amazon SNS for instance, you can send notifications to [multiple platforms](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/).

Comment: Azure and amazon both are providing search feature as listed in their documents to search in any files(txt,doc) and database tables too.so what i am asking is before when this cloud platforms were not available we are also doing this functionality so why to use azure or amazon search functionality?

Comment: That is true. Before these services were available, people where implementing it themselves. But, they had significant trouble doing so. With improvements in technology, they are now readily available, so people prefer to use these rather than doing it in the painful old method. Wouldn't you prefer to use a mobile app to book a cab rather than to go the street and wait for one?

Comment: Also, nowadays the amount of data people store has increased. Which is why we hear so much of "Big data" everywhere. So accessing and managing them has become more troublesome than before. Searching for data is just an instance of this problem. Even small companies can store terrabytes of data without trouble these days (thanks to cloud solutions).